# java - how to make an image using setRGB?

Tags: java

i have 2D array to keep color component value :

```
p[pixel_value][red]
p[pixel_value][green]
p[pixel_value][blue]
```

i just dont know how to use them to make an image.

i read about [setRGB](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt.geom/how-to-set-and-get-the-values-of-pixels-in-a-buffered.html), what i understand is i should mix all of them to become a RGBArray. then how to make it?

is it any better way to make an image without setRGB ? i need some explanation.

Comment: setRGB expects a packed int value which represents the RGB(A) value of the pixel. Probably the easiest way is via the java.awt.Color class

Comment: @MadProgrammer We meet again. Have a look at  my answer, as always :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `setRGB()` can be used to set the color of a pixel of an already existing image. You can open an already existing image and set all the pixels of it, using the values stored in your 2D array.
You can do it like this:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image which you want to change the pixels"));
for(int width=0; width < img.getWidth(); width++)
{
    for(int height=0; height < img.getHeight(); height++)
    {
          Color temp = new Color(p[pixel_value][red], p[pixel_value][green], p[pixel_value][blue]);
          img.setRGB(width, height, temp.getRGB());
    }
}
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("where you want to store this new image"));
```

Like this, you can iterate over all the pixels and set their color accordingly.

NOTE: By doing this, you will lose your original image. This is just a way which I know.

Comment: i tried your code,the pixel value of image result and the array value is different. i.e. p[0][red] = 168, the red value for the first pixel of the image result is 153.

Comment: my bad, jpg is lossy compression, i use png instead. and the problem solved. thank you.

Comment: Happy to know that your issue is solved. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).  Create a `BufferedImage` of type `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, if RGB is what you want, with a specified width and height.

> QuickFact:
>   The BufferedImage subclass describes an Image with an accessible
>   buffer of image data.

Then, call the `getRaster()` method to get a [`WritableRaster`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html)

> QuickFact:
>   This class extends Raster to provide pixel writing capabilities.

Then, use the `setPixel(int x, int y, double[] dArray)` method to set the pixels.

**Update:**

If all you want is to read an image, use the [`ImageIO.read(File f)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) method. It will allow you to read an image file in just one method call.

**Somewhat SSCCE:**

```
BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Maybe setPixel(int, int, int[]) might be a better solution based on the OPs original question. +1 non the less

Answer (score 1):

You want to manually set RGB values?

You need to know that since an `int` is 32bit it contains all 4 rgb values (1 for the transparency).

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx
^Alpha     ^red    ^green    ^blue
```

You can accomplish using 4 int values by the use of binary arithmetic:

```
int rgb = (red << 16) && () (green << 8) & (blue);
bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
```

IN the above you can add `Alpha` as well if needed. You just "push" the binary codes into the right places.